# React Native drop down menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i create drop down menu, that looks like that in React Native?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by customizing of some popup modules such as this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-menu